# Average commits per merge to Master using gitflow

Tags: git, gitflow

I'm currently working alone on a project, but I still use **Git** since it is a really powerful tool. I use [gitflow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) methodology, and today I have merged to **master** with **77 commits**. I was surprised since I wasn't expecting this big number, but it made sense since I had added over 4 features in a 2 week iteration.

What's the average commit number per `merge` to **master** in a project, let's say with 2 developers working on it? If there's any statistical study that back this up, it would be a great resource.

Comment: [Why are developer commit statistics harmful?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/132363/31260)

Comment: Recommended reading: **[Productivity 2.0](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Productivity-20)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about **how many** commits, and not about **how many** features either. It's about **when** you want to make a release. You merge to master when you want to stick a version number to the current state of the project and let your users upgrade(actually, according to formal git-flow you need a release branch for that - but that's usually an overkill for small projects).

Even if all your users are using the bleeding edge version in `develop`, it helps to think that you have users that download stable versions **not via Git**. To allow these users to upgrade you need to close the version, tag it with a version number, archive it and upload it to the download server. When you would want to do all this to allow your users to upgrade - then you merge to master. Not when the commit count reaches some arbitrary number...